# My function stops on the first value and I want it to keep going

Tags: python, function, for-loop, return, plotly-dash

I'm working on a dashboard with information about tennis professional players.

I got this for loop and I'm getting the desired output:

```
for ind in df.index:
    if df['Winner'][ind] == 'Nadal R.' and df['Loser'][ind] == 'Djokovic N.':
        print(df.iloc[ind]['Location'], ': ', df.iloc[ind]['Wsets'], '-', df.iloc[ind]['Lsets'])
```

OUTPUT:

```
Madrid :  2.0 - 0.0
Rome :  2.0 - 0.0
Rome :  2.0 - 1.0
Paris :  3.0 - 0.0
Rome :  2.0 - 1.0
```

But when I try to pass it into my dash app I have to create a function for the callback to work.

So I defined the following function (notice that `input_value1` and `input_value_2` are the same that in the code above by default):

```
def update_output_div(input_value1, input_value2):

    for ind in df.index:
        if df['Winner'][ind] == input_value1 and df['Loser'][ind] == input_value2:
            return df.iloc[ind]['Location'], ': ', df.iloc[ind]['Wsets'], '-', df.iloc[ind ['Lsets']
```

OUTPUT:

```
Madrid :  2.0 - 0.0
```

What I want to do is to display on my dash app the same output as the code on top.

Comment: (btw the reason for the single line output from your function is that you use `return` which promptly terminates the function. Compare this to `print()` in your first snippet which allows the loop to continue.)

Answer (score 2):

`return` closes your function

```
def update_output_div(input_value1, input_value2):
    res = []
    for ind in df.index:
        if df['Winner'][ind] == input_value1 and df['Loser'][ind] == input_value2:
            res.append(f"{df.iloc[ind]['Location']}: {df.iloc[ind]['Wsets']}-{df.iloc[ind ['Lsets']}")
    return res
```